# Can't display results where the ending matches

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a rhyme dictionary, and I have a database table with 3 coloumns, the user will search the database and the search keywords will search database where the ending of the word matches with the word in textbox.

When I enter some keyword into textbox

**I get ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.**

[**This is how my database looks like**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6seUH.png)

Here is how my aspx looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Kafiye Dizini - Türkçe Kafiye Bulma Sözlüğü - Uyak Bulucu Sözlük - İstediğiniz harf ile biten kelimeleri bulan sözlük</title>
    <meta name="description" content="İstediğiniz harfler ile biten kelimeleri bulmanızı sağlayan sözlük" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>



                <div class="top">
                    <div class="email">İletişim: fahrettinveysel@gmail.com</div>
                </div>

                <div class="leftcontainer">
                </div>

                <div class="middlecontainer">
                    <div class="title">Kafiye Dizini</div>
                    <div class="subtitle">İstediğiniz harf veya hece ile biten kelimeleri bulmanızı sağlayan sözlük</div>
                    <div class="searchcontainer">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="resultboxcontainer">
                        <div id="resultbox1" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="resultbox2" runat="server"></div>
                        <div id="resultbox3" runat="server"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="idefix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="rightcontainer">
                    <div class="ornekarama">
                        <div class="ornekaramabaslik">Örnek Arama</div>
                        <input type="text" class="ornekaramatextbox" value="rop" disabled="disabled" />
                        <div class="ornekaramasonuclar">filantrop<br />gardırop<br />hipermetrop<br />mikrop<br />mizantrop</div>
                    </div>
                </div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=kafiyedizini;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT kelime1,kelime2,kelime3 FROM kelimeler LIKE @arama", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arama", "%" + TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    resultbox1.InnerHtml += dr.GetString(0);
                    resultbox2.InnerHtml += dr.GetString(1);
                    resultbox3.InnerHtml += dr.GetString(2);
                }
            }

            cnn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            resultbox1.InnerHtml += "please enter data";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT kelime1,kelime2,kelime3 FROM kelimeler where kelime1 LIKE @arama`

Comment: Please check the comment above this by @Rene..

Comment: @Hasan Don't rollback mindlessly. I know that you intended to add more information to your original post, but you've also rolled by my readability fixes.

Comment: @BartoszKP sorry didn't see your fixes.

Comment: @HasanYılmaz Seems that I'm the one to say sorry :) I didn't notice that you've asked two similar questions in a row - I've edited the other one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial sql statement in your question should look like this

```
SELECT kelime1,kelime2,kelime3 FROM kelimeler where kelime1 LIKE @arama OR kelime2 LIKE @arama or kelime3 like @arama
```

You missed the where and the fields you want to use in your like statement.

to have each result in a separate 'box' you better investigate how a GridView works or a DataRepeater.

Closest in your initial code what could work, including support for handling null/emtpy values for one the fields returned, nicely filling the 3 resultboxes:

```
        var f1 = dr.GetString(0);
        var f2 = dr.GetString(1);
        var f3 = dr.GetString(2);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f1)) 
            resultbox1.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div>{0}</div>",f1);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f2)) 
            resultbox2.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div>{0}</div>",f2);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f3)) 
            resultbox1.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div>{0}</div>",f3);
```

Comment: It is very confusing if you ask a question, then edit it in such way that my answer no longer make sense. There is no penalty for asking a new good question that elaborates on the first question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing WHERE part of the SQL query

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.Id LIKE '%asd%'
```

I also think, dr.Read() executes PER ROW.

Hope this helps